# How can I make image gallery works with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying use a image gallery on my index page. But it's been really difficult get expect behavior. This is my code:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-8.col-sm-8.col-xs-8
      - 4.times do |i|
        .col-md-1.col-sm-1.col-xs-1
          %img.img-responsive.img-rounded{:alt => "", :src => "http://placehold.it/300"}
    .col-md-4 //consider simple code in for this column !
```

I tried before add container, rows and others but always the images get smaller. Is smth wrong with my code? Am I making some mistake with bootstrap behavior?

Comment: Please, what's wrong with question?

Comment: [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new and hope this is an answer that might help you:

I don't know why you're filling it like this.

The container has (in Bootstrap counting) a width of 12. So you can put in 12 elements with a class of `col-**-1` or 4 of `col-**-3`. If you don't fill it up, it won't appear bigger although there would be enough space.

Here is one solution in plain html with colums of size 3, so 4 images are displayed in a good size:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

BTW: Whats this for a cool markup language?

Comment: it is haml. I'm not a html front-end expert and wouldn't like to spend time writting html/style code. So I've tried haml to try increase a little bit my productivity